# MYSQL request optimization select by simple column

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query like

```
SELECT `table1`.* 
  FROM `table1` 
 WHERE `table1`.`table2_id` IN (1,2,6,12,53,666)
```

and it works more than 20 seconds

Explain looks like:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                 | key                              | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1                   | NULL       | range | table2_id                                                                     | table2_id                           | 4       | NULL | 74778 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `table2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `table3_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `field3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_of_index_id` (`table3_id`),
  KEY `other_name_of_index` (`field2`),
  KEY `table2_id` (`table2_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=86623178 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @darkhouse he said it takes 20 seconds to get result, and need to be optimized but it looks can't be optimized more

Comment: I agree with @Joseph, there is not much to optimise on this query. Perhaps you could list the fields you want instead of using *. Your table seems to be big, so you may want to tweak the mysql configuration to increase the speed. But that question is for the dba site, not for SO.

Comment: Do you need to select all of columns?

Comment: You have an index, the EXPLAIN shows that the query is using the index. I suspect you're just trying to use an underpowered database server. Perhaps take a look at amount of RAM allocated to buffer pool. Perhaps check `iotop` to see if your I/O is backed up. In any case, this question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, because Stack Overflow is for code questions, but there's no code solution that will improve the query.

Comment: I see 6 items in the `IN` clause, but an estimated `74778` rows -- Which is more realistic?  If you stripped down the query, you may have removed the information on which we can explain the `20 seconds`.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Answer (score -2):

You can use index to fetch the result quickly. But, Indexing will take more space to generate and store in the database. So, if you are fine to utilize speed compare to space, Indexing will be used with following SQL statement.

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX(`table2_id`);
```